# I have used alarm manager to schedule a notification, but is not working if i used the calender time

Tags: android

This is the code which i have used on click of my set alarm button

```
 alarmOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getMinute());


                int hourString = timePicker.getHour();
                int minuteString = timePicker.getMinute();


                //intent.putExtra("extra","alarm_on");
                setAlarmTxt("Alarm set to "+ hourString+":"+minuteString);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
                //alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),0,pendingIntent);
               // sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
```

When i used this code, it is working...

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealti
  me(),pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RTC_WAKEUP to use system current time and ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP to specify time in interval of time elapsed since device boot time.

That is, either

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealti
  me(),pendingIntent);
```

or

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for details

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, i have used this   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

Comment: I got the problem, when i used the current time, it is working, but when i set the time from timepicker, my receiver is not called, when i use this code to set the calender time.. see this - calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getMinute());

Comment: Hey, thanks, i solved the problem, it was gmt - 5:30 problem, now its working